# Looking for code example to refresh a bundle during/right after the OSGi container loads

Tags: osgi

I am looking for a way to problematically refresh a bundle with a certain symbolic name after/during the OSGi container loads. Can someone please provide a code example?

Comment: It would be good to describe why you need to perform this refresh, so that others might help you get around having to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OSGi env, you can use ServiceTracker to track service status like register service, removing service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, but registering a FrameworkListener that catches the STARTED event will allow you to find one when the framework startup is done.